# Add latitud/longitud dot to my map is not working (R STUDIO)

Tags: r, maps

I ploted an Argentina map and then I took the region I am interested in. But the problem is, I can not plot specific dots in specific latitudes and longitudes. It does not work.
And I want to plot different dots with values all over the map!!
This is the website where I took the data to plot the map: https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html (I only downloaded a file, that was all).

```
library(sp)   
gadm <- readRDS("gadm36_ARG_1_sf.rds")
gadm<-gadm[2]
plot(gadm)
mapaposta= plot(gadm, col = 'lightgrey', border = 'black',ylim = c(-40,-27),xlim=c(-68,-55))
points(-63.4,-34.1167,col=2)
```

This is the plot I am getting with no dots on it!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the coordinate reference system of the spatial polygons data frame.

```
library(sp)   
# download data from https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_ARG_1_sp.rds
gadm <- readRDS("gadm36_ARG_1_sp.rds")
proj4string(gadm)=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
plot(gadm, col = 'lightgrey', border = 'black',ylim = c(-40,-27),xlim=c(-68,-55))
points(-63.4,-34.1167,col=2)
```

[image]